# How to change the props of bullet slider in Ionic 4?

Tags: css, ionic-framework, ionic4

How to change the props of bullet in ion-slider (color, size and position)
I apply the snippets of the next link, but not working in ionic 4
[Change ion-slides pager dot color](https://forum.ionicframework.com/t/change-ion-slides-pager-dot-color/102752/2)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I just find out the answer

You should apply your styling as shown as an example here:

```
.swiper-pagination-bullet {
    --bullet-background: #00a0be;
    width: 12px;
    height: 12px;
  }

  .swiper-pagination-bullet-active {
      width: 12px;
      height: 12px;
     --bullet-background: transparent;
  }

  .swiper-container-horizontal>.swiper-pagination-bullets {
    bottom: 5%!important;
  }
```

Those are the classes needed to change the styling of the dots. Hope it works for you.